# Unable to install ROS TurtleBOT - Unable to locate package

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**My OS :**
Distributor ID: **Ubuntu**
Description: **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS**
Release: **20.04**
Codename: **focal**

My ROS

```
/rosdistro: noetic
/rosversion: 1.15.8
```

When I try to intall turtlebot packages using this

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps ros-indigo-turtlebot-interactions ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator ros-indigo-kobuki-ftdi ros-indigo-rocon-remocon ros-indigo-rocon-qt-library ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar-msgs
```

I get this Error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot-interactions
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-kobuki-ftdi
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rocon-remocon
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rocon-qt-library
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ar-track-alvar-msgs
```

Even if I change the *distro* to *kinetic* or *noetic* , that still produces the same error messages with given *distro* name.

Why is this happening? Kindly help ASAP.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365247/unable-to-install-ros-turtlebot---unable-to-locate-package/) by [Paul Pavish](https://answers.ros.org/users/62559/paul-pavish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2020-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to install indigo packages when your ROS distro is noetic (as it should be under Ubuntu focal). You need to find and install the corresponding noetic packages instead. The turtlebot packages doesn't seem to exist anymore in noetic, so I think you will need to use http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot3 instead.

---

Originally posted by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) with karma: 553 on 2020-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul Pavish](https://answers.ros.org/users/62559/paul-pavish/) on 2020-11-11**:
Yes your right @chfritz. That was really helpful.